# How to sort by when doing server-side request on a datasource prefetch?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a datasource A which can have several B. I've set the prefetch so, from client-side, when you request a A, you also get its associated B sorted by "update_date" (DESC).

On server-side, I'm also requesting some A, and I've set the prefetch the `query` object so I'm getting my B. But they're not sorted by "update_date".

Do you know why ? Do you if I have to do it by script or I'm missing an option in the `query` object ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Acourding documentation: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/server#Query

```
var query = app.models.Project.newQuery();
query.sorting.Manager.name._descending();
query.run();
```

About relation:
A Manager can have many associated Project records. And a Project can have at most one associated Manager.

it's possible to setup relation sort[image] so projects will be sorted asc by name.

Comment: In my case, A has several B (an array), and this array should be sorted accorded to the prefetch configuration. In your case, if there can be at most one Manager, there is no point sorting them :)

Comment: in my case Projects will be sorted by manager's name.
If it is need to sort Manager's projects, it's possible to setup sorting field and direction in model relation tab.